# MongooseJS object undefined inside callback function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I'm trying to write an endpoint for an API that will return all orders for a given user. My issue is that when I try to query the database using mongoose's findById function, the 'user' object is undefined in the callback function and I can't query the orders subdoc. To add to the confusion, I can get it to work if I don't use a callback function, but then I don't have proper error handling.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

var order_model = require('../models/order');
var user_model = require('../models/user');

router.get('/:userid/order/', function (req, res) {

    // This works???
    var u = user_model.findById(req.params.userid);
    res.json(u.orders);

});
```

The following code throws the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'orders' of undefined".

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

var order_model = require('../models/order');
var user_model = require('../models/user');
router.get('/:userid/order/', function (req, res) {

    // This throws an error.
    user_model.findById(req.params.userid).then(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(user.orders);
    });
});
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ordersSchema = require('./order').schema;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    showroom: String,
    orders: [ordersSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

order.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var lineItemsSchema = require('./lineitem').schema;

var ordersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    trackingNumber: Number,
    lineItems: [lineItemsSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', ordersSchema);
```

Any help / explanation of this behavior would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the `then` callback is `user`, not `err`.

Either use a traditional callback:

```
user_model.findById(req.params.userid, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return; // Need to return here to not continue with non-error case
    }
    res.json(user.orders);
});
```

Or chain a call to `catch` on the promise to separately handle errors:

```
user_model.findById(req.params.userid).then(function (user) {
    res.json(user.orders);
}).catch(function(err) {
    res.send(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually query like this, it work perfect :

```
user_model.find(_id : req.params.userid)
    .exec((err, user) => {
       if(err){
          //handle error
       }
       return res.status(200).json(user.orders);
    })
});
```